# Group by in SQL with commas

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle SQL and i have a question regarding `group by` command.

I have the following table:

```
Column_A (int)
Column_B (int)
```

Example for data in the table:

```
Column_A | Column_B
 11      |    2
 23      |    3
 32      |    4
 32      |    10
 11      |    23
 23      |    11
 44      |    1
 23      |    5
```

I want to Group by `Column_A` while the values of `Column_b` will be terminated by commas. Output table:

```
Column_A | Column_B
 11      |  2, 23
 23      |  3, 11
 32      |  4, 10, 5
 44      |  1
```

Any recommendation how to do that?

Comment: This is technically speaking not grouping but reducing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

```
SELECT Column_A, listagg( Column_B, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP( order by Column_B)
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Column_A
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was sloppy again with the code formatting, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LISTAGG:

```
SELECT column_A,
       LISTAGG(column_B, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_B) column_B
  FROM your_table
 GROUP
    BY column_A
```